# Generating an excel spill array with a % uplift on each line

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The output I am looking for:-

[image: Example]

This is no problem until I try to use dynamic arrays.

A % uplift is applied to the closing value of each line and repeated for a variable number of lines.

I must be missing something I think.

- If I try and use SCAN that gives access to intermediate results and I can calculate, but I can't retrieve the percentage to apply to the line.
- If I try to use map I can pass the rate, the unit amount and the total. But this doesn't work because the total can be changed by any interation.
- I have the same issue with byrow.

I only have the limited editing of android mobile on my phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options - scan is the most obvious one to use because it accumulates, but it can only produce a single result for each array element which is input to it. You could calculate the balances like this:

```
=LET(uplift,C4:C13,
dep,D4:D13,
seq,SEQUENCE(ROWS(uplift)),
SCAN(0,seq,LAMBDA(a,c,a*INDEX(uplift,c)+INDEX(dep,c)+a)))
```

where the trick is to generate a sequence which is used to index the two ranges rather than try to access them directly.

Then calculate the uplifts separately perhaps just by a simple array formula:

```
=C4:C13*G3:G12
```

Another way is to use reduce - this can produce two or more results each time the lambda is called e.g.

```
=LET(uplift,C4:C13,
dep,D4:D13,
seq,SEQUENCE(ROWS(uplift)),
DROP(REDUCE({0,0},seq,LAMBDA(a,c,LET(prev,TAKE(a,-1,-1),VSTACK(a,HSTACK(INDEX(uplift,c)*prev,prev*INDEX(uplift,c)+INDEX(dep,c)+prev))))),1))
```

This works in the same way as before except that you have to refer to the last element of the current output array using Take for each calculation.

---

You can also make these formulas more dynamic using Torow with the option to ignore blanks, so assuming the original data has headers:

```
=LET(uplift,DROP(TOCOL(C:C,1),1),
dep,DROP(TOCOL(D:D,1),1),
seq,SEQUENCE(ROWS(uplift)),
SCAN(0,seq,LAMBDA(a,c,a*INDEX(uplift,c)+INDEX(dep,c)+a)))
```

and

```
=LET(uplift,DROP(TOCOL(C:C,1),1),
dep,DROP(TOCOL(D:D,1),1),
seq,SEQUENCE(ROWS(uplift)),
DROP(REDUCE({0,0},seq,LAMBDA(a,c,LET(prev,TAKE(a,-1,-1),VSTACK(a,HSTACK(INDEX(uplift,c)*prev,prev*INDEX(uplift,c)+INDEX(dep,c)+prev))))),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Tom. I will fiddle with both of those so I can understand them properly. I had figured I needed intermediate results but was struggling.

Comment: I prefer the 2nd, because it doesn't scan (I have an occasional issue on android where scan produces erroneous results until I edit the formula - there is no force recalc on android). However the formula editor is really difficult over 3 lines because it's not resizable oland usually doesn't scroll properly. 

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox if you want to scroll down in your formula bar and it seems stuck, scroll your file down and back while having the formula bar active and than you'll find the formula bar is responding to scrolling again. I was real annoyed by it at first too, but found out that's how it seems to work.